# EditText in Layout not full width

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android

I have problem with xml. Why my EditText doesn't show for full screen width? It showing about 80% of screen width, but not all..

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="@color/colorGray"
        android:layout_weight=".35" >


        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightCont"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the `EditText` is wrapped in a `ScrollView` wich takes 0.35 weight of the screen. So it will expand until it reaches the boundaries of its parent `ViewGroup.`

To test this, change the weight of ScrollView to 1:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: Hmm.. My layout design is : http://www.part.lt/img/5447cd41dbe169cb9395974738e3df32265.jpg
and my xml layout structure looks like this:

`<LinearLayout>
 <ScrollView>
      <HorizontalScrollView>
 <LinearLayout> 
 </LinearLayout>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
 </ScrollView>
 <ScrollView>
     <HorizontalScrollView>
 <LinearLayout>
      <EditText />
 </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
 </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>`

Answer (score 1):

beside what Andy Res said, a scrollview in a scrollview is not recommended. newer android versions can handle that but older one will have trouble determining which scrollview should scroll on touch events.

Also a LinearLayout with wrap_content around the EditText with fill_parent should result in a pure wrap_content behavior of the EditText, too.

You should rethink your layout.